# dotnet console app, using generic host, HostedService, Windows Task Scheduler stays in running state

Tags: .net-core, console-application, windows-task-scheduler

Trying to figure out why my console app won't stop running.

Using the following approach in a dotnet core application main method:

```cs
await new HostBuilder().
...
 .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
  {     
     services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>(); 
  })
 .UseConsoleLifetime()
 .Build()
 .RunAsync();
```

Publishing and scheduling that task from the Windows Task Scheduler using the following settings works:

[image: Windows Task Scheduler settings]

All good so far. All code is properly executed. However, the task stays running, the process never ends. (not even after pressing refresh on the UI of the task scheduler)

Is this expected? If not, how do I get the process to terminate?

If expected, does it still make sense then, to use Generic Host / Hosted Service in a scheduled console app that just starts, runs, and stops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Answer based on [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/2.2.0)*

This behavior is expected, due to your usage of the [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host):

It keeps running until shut down or disposed, and you have no shutdown mechanism in place. I assume you expect the [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host) to shut down after [IHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.startasync) of your `MyHostedService` ran to completion. This is not the case, because there might be other [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice) implementations registered and executed in sequence, and/or a long running [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice) which returns control when its [ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync) is not completing synchronously to allow other services to run in parallel.

To stop your application gracefully after your `MyHostedService` completes when running the host via [RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostingabstractionshostextensions.runasync), you should [constructor-inject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) the [IApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.iapplicationlifetime) into your `MyHostedService` and call [StopApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.iapplicationlifetime.stopapplication) after your Task has completed.

```cs
internal class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

    public MyHostedService(IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //your scheduled work

        _appLifetime.StopApplication();
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Also, the application may be stopped via either [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit) or [Console.CancelKeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress), both events are subscribed to by the [ConsoleLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.internal.consolelifetime), which is pre-registered as the default lifetime implementation.

You can read more about lifetime management in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host).

*Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 3.0.0 - currently in preview - marked `IApplicationLifetime` obsolete and recommends using `IHostApplicationLifetime` instead*

Comment: That is an incredibly detailed answer, I'll try it out and get back to you, Thanks!